# How can I call a parent method from the instantiating class?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, class, methods, extension-methods

In my project all of my view classes are extensions of a base view class which handles all common aspects to the views, including error messages. In one of the view extensions I am creating an instance of another 'helper' class which may need to output error messages.

Is there any way that I can reference my `addError` method from the parent of the class that created the instance of the helper class, directly from within a method of the helper class itself?

e.g.

```
class baseview {
    ...
    public function addError($message) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

class pageview extends baseview {
    ...
    $helper = new helper();
   ...
}

class helper {
    ...
    public function myFunction($var) {
        if( $var ) { ... }
        else { theClassThatInstantiatedMe::addError('Error Message') }
    }
    ...
}
```

~ OR ~

Could someone please suggest a better way to structure my system to better handle this type of situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 simple solutions are:

Store the parent class in the helper class:

```
class pageview extends baseview {
    ...
    $helper = new helper($this);
   ...
}

class helper {
    function __construct($parent)
    {
        $this->_parent=$parent;
    }
    ...
    $this->_parent->addError("...");
}
```

Othwerwise make the addError function public and static so that you can call it in the helper class without store the parent class instance:

```
class baseview {
    ...
    static public function addError($message) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

class helper{
     ...
     baseview::addError("...");
}
```

Comment: I prefer the neatness of your second suggestion so I've gone with that. I knew there had to be a simple straight forward way to do it, brilliant thank you!

Comment: Whooops!! Actually using `static` means that I can't access the class variables with `$this->var`, which I kind of need so that the base class (and subsequently the child class) 'knows' when it has an error message to display! So I've switched to your first example and all is well again!

Answer (score 0):

From your example, I would have supposed that you meant baseview to be used universally, and so "baseview::addError('Error Message');"

But from the text, I gather that there may be differnt classes. In that case, you are going to have to pass a reference to the creating class into the helper, like this:

```
class pageview extends baseview {
...
$helper = new helper($this);
```

...
}

class helper {
    protected $creator;
    ...
    public function myFunction($creator, $var) {

```
    $this->creator = $creator;
    if( $var ) { ... }
    else { $creator->addError('Error Message') }
}
...
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want clean code, you should separate wiring (object creation) and logic.

Here is **THE** pdf all coders should have read at least once: [Writing Testable Code](http://misko.hevery.com/attachments/Guide-Writing%20Testable%20Code.pdf)

It is a pdf found on Misko Hevery's blog (A google "clean code" evangelist).

If you prefer videos, you can check these: [Misko's conferences at Google](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=misko%20hevery&aq=f)